# Table schema name doesn;'t match to the data model class name in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

Can anyone please advise, why is that the schema names in the Prosgre DB and model class names don't match?
For example, my data model class name is 'User'.But, what exactly showing in my database is user_user.
May I know what is that happened?

Comment: Please show your model definition and the query code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django database tables are named `<app>_<model>`.

Your app's name is `user`, and your model's name is `User`, so the autogenerated name is `user_user`.

You can override this in the Meta class for a model if you need to, but that's generally not very Django:

```
class User(model.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'
```